# Why is "can" such an odd verb?

Tags: verbs, history, modal-verbs, defective-verbs

The English verb *can* is very strange for several reasons:

- It drops the *to* on any infinitive verb forms that follow it. That is, unlike in the verb *want* in the sentence *I want **to** eat*, you would not include the infinitive *to* marker in the sentence *I can eat*.
- *Can* itself has no infinitive form. A construction like *I like to can understand foreign languages* is not grammatical; you have to use the phrase *to be able*, as in, *I like to be able to understand foreign languages*.
- *Can* does not conjugate. Most verbs add an *s* or *es* when they have a third person singular subject, but *can* does not.
- You cannot add tense modifiers to *can*. *I will can*, *I canned*, *I had canned* and so on are all ungrammatical (unless you are talking about putting things in can). You have to use constructions like "I will be able to", "I could", "I had been able to", etc.

All of the other languages I know anything about do not share any of these characteristics in their corresponding verbs.

What are the historical reasons for why the verb *can* behaves so oddly in English?

Comment: The verbs *can, could, may, might, shall, should, will, would, must,* all behave the same way. They're called [*modals*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb), and other languages in the Germanic language family also have them.

Comment: Also, it's the only word I can think of whose negation is compressed into one word: cannot.

Comment: @JeffSahol: *Notwithstanding* fits too, I would say. And it’s not modern, but *won’t* used to be *wynnot*. Going back further, a lot of Old English words could be negated with *n-* (a shortening of *ne*), which is where we get *never* and *none*.

Comment: ...and on top of all that mess some idiot thought it's a good idea to give it a noun meaning too, describing a metal container...

Answer (score 8):

As Peter Shor indicates in his comment, these are [**modal verbs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) and are found in other Germanic languages as well. Their unusual conjugation is due to their historical source:

> Germanic modal verbs are [preterite-present verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preterite-present_verb#Preterite-presents), which means that
>   their present tense has the form of a vocalic preterite. This is the
>   source of the vowel alternation between singular and plural in German
>   and Dutch. **Because of their preterite origins, modal verbs also lack
>   the suffix (-s in modern English, -t in German and Dutch) that would
>   normally mark the third person singular form**.

[Preterite-present verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preterite-present_verb#Preterite-presents_in_Proto-Germanic) are a very old group of verbs found in Germanic languages that in turn descended from a set of Proto-Indo-European verbs. Originally these were [perfect-aspect verbs that referred to a present state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_verb#Stative).

The common characteristic is that the "present tense" of these verbs was conjugated like the "past tense" (essentially). In Modern English this now means that the present-tense "-s" ending is not used, and that modifiers like "to", "will", etc. can't be added. It happens that these verbs are all modals in Modern English, which probably helps preserve the unusual conjugation.

So this is a bit of a historical accident that made a lot more sense in PIE, and now is frozen that way.

Comment: I think the first-hand association would come from French; after all, 2/3 of the English words and grammar derive from French. (Which is not a Germanic language btw.)

Comment: @poepje many Modern English words did come from French, but our modal verbs all happen to derive from Germanic. Also, I don't know how you measure 2/3 of grammar.

Comment: Well I suppose it's a somewhat 'loose' measurement.. But that's what I used to learn at high school anyway :)

Comment: @poepje A high percentage of English vocabulary comes from French, but the grammar is by and large inherited (that is, Germanic). There are some French influences on grammar, but nowhere near two thirds, however one measures that.

Answer (score 6):

[Modal auxiliary verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) in English are **all** irregular, idiomatic, defective (which means they are missing normal inflected forms, viz. infinitive, past tense, past participle, and 3rdSg present), and very, very common. All the phenomena mentioned in the question are typical of modals, so *can* is simply a normal modal in this regard.

*Can* **does** have a couple of unique peculiarities, though. All modals have at least a logical Epistemic sense, about possibility and probability:

- *This can't be the place.*
- *This may be the place.*
- *This must be the place.*
- *He should be asleep by now.*

and a social/personal Deontic sense, about permission and obligation:

- *You can't carry that on the plane.*
- *You may leave your bag here.*
- *She must leave immediately.*
- *You should see a doctor about that.*

and *can* is no exception.

However, Epistemic *can* occurs only in [NPI](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) environments, and is usually ungrammatical without a Negative trigger.

- **This can be the place.*
- **She can have meant that.*

and *can* also has an additional sense, referring specifically to personal ability, rather than to permission or logical possibility:

- *She can run a marathon in under 2 hours.*

Comment: [Epistemic _can_ cannot occur in environments other than NPI environments.]                                       Yes it can!

Comment: This can be true. Possibly.

Comment: Epistemic _can_ in non-negative environments appears to be more common in UK Englishes than American.