# "will" vs. "would" in conditional clauses

Tags: subjunctive-mood

What's the difference between the following:

> 1. If he is in the US now, he **would** be in New York.
> 2. If he is in the US now, he **will** be in New York.

Does #2 necessarily mean that he will be in New York at a future date if the condition holds?

Can #2 mean that he must be in New York now if the condition holds?

"Will" can mean "must", can't it, as in "That will be John knocking at the door"?

Answer (score 1):

Context is the key.

1. For example, if you know that he is on his way to the US:

   If he is in the US (by) now, he will be in New York.
2. If you know that he's in the US, and are making a guess about the city:

   If he is in the US now, he would be in New York.
3. If you don't know where he is and are making both the assumptions:

   If he were in the US, he would be in New York.

Comment: The OP uses the same tense  "If he **is**" in both sentences.

Comment: Possible, depending upon the context and what is really intended. 

"would" can also be used, among others, in a situation of uncertainty. Therefore, "he would be in New York" = he will probably be in New York.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that in your answer you changed the tense, you wrote "If he **were**", the change in meaning is subtle.

Comment: Oh, that's the tense and form (one form, invariable for all pronouns, such as I, you, we, he, etc.) used while making an assumption.

Comment: So are you saying the OP has made a grammatical error? If that is the case, please edit your answer and address this point. Otherwise your second phrase is skirting the issue.

Comment: "If you know that he's in the US, and are making a **guess** about the city:" Then: *If you say he's in the US, he's **probably** in New York by now.* OR *he **could** be in New York*

Comment: Yeah, right, those are your alternatives! But from the original sentence, which has 'would', I'm drawing certain conclusions. Thus 'would be' = 'will probably be'. 'Would' can express an uncertainty, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) has taught us countless times (quoting from [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193041/77339)):

> Modal auxiliary verbs ("modals") are very irregular and have extremely
>   complex grammar. Every modal has two kinds of meaning: its **Epistemic**
>   sense and its **Deontic** sense.
>
> Epistemic meanings are abstract and refer to logical predictions and
>   conclusions: This might/must/could/should/may/will/would be the place.
>
> Deontic meanings are social and have to do with obligations,
>   permissions, and prohibitions: She may/can/should/must go to the ball.

`will` and `must` both are modals and both can have epistemic as well as deontic meanings. So yes, `will` can mean `must`, but `must` doesn't always imply certainty (as in, *"This must be where it took place", he speculated.*)

According to me, your first example is epistemic. The speaker is predicting he's in New York, certainty isn't guaranteed.

The `if...will` construction is that of the [conditional mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood), not the subjunctive mood as you've tagged it. It doesn't define limits of certainty.

Compare:

- IF I give you 12 apples, you WILL have a dozen apples. (absolutely)
- IF you eat 12 apples, you WILL fall ill. (maybe, maybe not)

Bottom line, you should never rely on modal for certainty. Introduce other suitable words in the sentence.

> If he is in the US now, he will **possibly/probably/definitely** be in New York.

EDIT: You can't use `will` to speculate about the future, and you can't use `would` to speculate about now. If you use `will`, you'd be speculating about the present. See sense 6 in [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/will). If you use `would`, you'd be speculating about the future.

Comment: Would #2 not be the case for someone stating it with certainty? I seem to recall a lot of similar sentences e.g. in movies where the protagonist *knows* where the person they're looking for will be found. Knowing with certainty might be an overstatement on their part, but not specifically grammatically incorrect, no?

Comment: @Flater So, for you, the would-version, i.e. 1, is less definite than 2?

Comment: It seems to me "would" is more a statement of historical evidence, or assumption about where he'd want to go. It's been the case often, so it's fair to presume the same thing happening now. Whereas "will" is more focused on it being correct *now* (for whatever reason). This is just interpretation though. Not application of known grammatical rules.

Comment: @Flater: You're right. Edited the post.

Comment: @Flater  You just produced a sentence of the sort that interests me: "If you use will, you'd be speculating about the present."  What does  'would' mean here?

Comment: In my opinion, "would" is less certain, meaning you're relying either on historical evidence (of him having done similar things in the past under similar circumstances), or an educated guess (it's normal for people to do so, so why not him as well?).

Comment: @Flater: Are you talking about the `would` in `you'd be speculating`?

Comment: Was just responding to OP's question. Which I only now notice he probably wrongly confused me and you (poster vs commenter), making my answer a bit misguided, I guess.

Comment: @Flater: Just so you know, `would` is merely here to express the conditional mood. It doesn't restrict the level of certainty. `If I gave you 1 apple each day for a week, I WOULD have given you 7 apples in total`. Fairly certain.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction  I noticed that sentence I was asking about was written by you, not by Flater. It is different from the kind of example you've given. It uses the present tense in the main clause, as in "If you USE will, you'D be speculating about the present. "

Comment: @Apollyon: Same template, consider: IF you use (the word) CAT (at any point in your life from today), you WOULD (probably) be talking about the cutest animal in the world. IF you come to my home right now (at present, NOT tomorrow, NOT yesterday), you WILL see one. Get it now?